# DC.js Graphing Tags

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

With the example data

```
var data = [
    {Name: 'Mr A', Spent: 40, Year: 2011, tags: ['a', 'b', 'c']},
    {Name: 'Mr B', Spent: 10, Year: 2011, tags: ['c']},
    {Name: 'Mr C', Spent: 40, Year: 2011, tags: ['a']},
    {Name: 'Mr A', Spent: 70, Year: 2012, tags: ['c', 'b']},
    {Name: 'Mr B', Spent: 20, Year: 2012, tags: ['b']},
    {Name: 'Mr B', Spent: 50, Year: 2013, tags: ['a', 'b', 'c']},
    {Name: 'Mr C', Spent: 30, Year: 2013, tags: ['a', 'b']}
];
```

I am trying to create a dc.js row chart that would show each unique tag and allow me to reduce the values graphed by each tag. So far I have this code which allows me to reduce the tags to their spent sums:

```
function reduceAdd(p, v) {
  v.tags.forEach (function(val, idx) {
     p[val] = (p[val] || 0) + v.Spent;
  });
  return p;
}

function reduceRemove(p, v) {
   v.tags.forEach (function(val, idx) {
     p[val] -= v.Spent;
  });
  return p;
}

function reduceInitial() {
  return {};  
}
var tagsDim = ndx.dimension(function(d)  {return d.tags; } );
tagsGroup = tagsDim.groupAll().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);
console.log(tagsGroup.value())
'{ a: 160, b: 210, c: 170 }'
```

This gives the reduced sums correctly. But, because this is a groupAll object dc.js can't graph it, so I am not quite sure where to go from here. Is it even possible for dc.js to access the tags in the array. Would it be better to calculate the sums a different way?

Comment: You will end up with non-disjoint groups this way - since a row can belong to as many groups as there are tags, rows will get counted multiple times. Also any other chart that does ordinary sums across rows will get a different total. Is this what you want?

Comment: Pretty sure crossfilter does not support this, so you'd have to implement it yourself. Easy enough to adapt the groups you are getting as a [fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#filter-the-data-before-its-charted); the tricky part will be writing the [filter function](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_filterFunction).

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, here is the code I use to create a rowchart with multiple tags. It should work with your data.

You can have a try here : http://jsfiddle.net/ewm76uru/30/

```
var data = [
{id:1, author:'foo', tags: ['tag1','tag2','tag3']},
{id:2, author:'foo', tags: ['tag3']},
{id:3, author:'foo', tags: ['tag1']},
{id:4, author:'bar', tags: ['tag2','tag3']},
{id:5, author:'bar', tags: ['tag3']},
{id:6, author:'bar', tags: ['tag2','tag3']},
{id:7, author:'bar', tags: ['tag1','tag2']}
]; 

    var content=crossfilter(data);

    // table
    var idDimension = content.dimension(function (d) { return d.id; });
    var table = dc.dataTable("#idtable");
    table.dimension(idDimension)
        .group(function(d){ return "ITEMS" })
        .columns([
            function(d){return d.id+" : "; },
    function(d){return d.author+"&nbsp;"},
            function(d){return d.tags;},
        ])

    // author chart
    var authorDimension = content.dimension(function (d) { return d.author; });
    var authorgroup = authorDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return 1; })
    authorChart = dc.rowChart('#idauthor');
    authorChart
        .width(300)
        .renderLabel(true)
        .gap(2)
        .margins({top: 10, left: 10, right: 20, bottom: 40})
        .group(authorgroup)
        .dimension(authorDimension)
        .elasticX(true)
        .transitionDuration(1000)
        .colors(d3.scale.category10())
        .label(function (d) { return d.key })
        .xAxis().ticks(5);

    // tags chart
    function reduceAdd(p, v) {
        v.tags.forEach (function(val, idx) {
            p[val] = (p[val] || 0) + 1; //increment counts
        });
        return p;
    }

    function reduceRemove(p, v) {
        v.tags.forEach (function(val, idx) {
            p[val] = (p[val] || 0) - 1; //decrement counts
        });
        return p;
    }

    function reduceInitial() {
        return [];
    }


    var tags = content.dimension(function (d) { return d.tags });
    var tags2 = content.dimension(function (d) { return d.tags });
    var groupall = tags.groupAll();
    var tagsGroup = groupall.reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial).value();
    tagsGroup.all = function() {
        var newObject = [];
        for (var key in this) {
            if (this[key] && key != "all") {
                newObject.push({
                    key: key,
                    value: this[key]
                });
            }
        }
        return newObject;
    }

    var tagsChart = dc.rowChart("#idtags")
    tagsChart
        .width(400)
        .height(200)
        .renderLabel(true)
        .labelOffsetY(10)
        .gap(2)
        .group(tagsGroup)
        .dimension(tags2)
        .elasticX(true)
        .transitionDuration(1000)
        .colors(d3.scale.category10())
        .label(function (d) { return d.key })
        .on("filtered", function(c,f) {
            //tags2.filter(f)
        })
        .filterHandler (function (dimension, filters) {
            dimension.filter(null);
            dimension.filterFunction(function (d) {
                for (var i=0; i < filters.length; i++) {
                    if (d.indexOf(filters[i]) <0) return false;
                }
                return true;
            });



            return filters;
        })
    .xAxis().ticks(5);

    dc.renderAll();
```

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain how to filter by multiple tags, with the tags filter updated